# Set double coordinates to GMaps

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, maps, coordinates

I have got 3 maps on my app, want to change longtitude and latitude with Parse.com if it's needed.

I follow this way:

```
String place1latitudeSTRING = "49.986595";
public Double place1latitude = Double.valueOf(place1latitudeSTRING);
String place1longitudeSTRING = "31.294509";
public Double place1longitude = Double.valueOf(place1longitudeSTRING);
```

then i download changes from Parse.com. In my LOG i can see that application really download new double. 
Then i have got condition:

```
Double list_maps_new_coordinates = maps_coordinates.get(6);
String place1longitudeChanged = Double.toString(list_maps_new_coordinates);
place1longitude = Double.valueOf(place1longitudeChanged);
```

And finally in my private void SetUpMap i have got this code:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(place1latitude, place1longitude))
```

Question: Why not change the coordinates? Where is mistake?

Comment: Reformatted the sample code blocks. There was no need for the ` ` when you are already using  indentation and the second block was indented too far.

Comment: @WillShackleford , ok, i understand. Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not that familiar with gmap API or Parse.com. I can see that it is taking a while to find an answer. Consider building an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it easier for more people to test the issue and get an answer faster.